# gulp concat js files into two min.js, lost library definition

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I'm using `gulp` to concat all js library to lib.js, and concat all self-writing js files to app.js, then I use gulp-inject to inject into my index.html, but chrome console shows the error `jQuery is not defined`

[image]
[image]